# Не удается найти указанный файл exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, плагин, сборка, exec

`Maven` не находит файл, который находится в папке `resourses`. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему, как и что поменять?

Ошибка:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) on project pathToCSVAndDateToInt: An exception occured while executing
the Java class. file.csv (Не удается найти указанный файл) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Код `java`:

```java
package org.example;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
        String[] arrayString;
        while((arrayString = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            System.out.println(arrayString);
        }
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pathToCSVAndDateToInt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.example.main</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-Dproperty=first</argument>
                        <argument>-Dproperty=second</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Сам файл лежит в папке ресурсы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
 ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
 InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("file.csv");
```

Если тяжело разобраться то можно получить файл.

```
URI uri = classloader.getResource("file.csv").getURI();

CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(uri)));
```

Comment: я немного не понял куда и зачем, поясните, пожалуйста, поподробнее. заранее спасибо.

Comment: Данный код превратит файл в ресурсах в поток. Далее поток передадите в файл ридер и всё

Comment: спасибо, попробую.

Comment: то есть, как я понял я передаю в new FileReader, is, с использованием String.valueOf ? Просто, без String, Intellij ругается

Comment: + я посмотрел ещё по этому делу, добавил плагин, maven-resources-plugin, но всё равно, безрезультатно...

Comment: Добавил файл если нужно. Можете его считать если что.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но Intellji IDEA ругается на вашу строчку, предлагает добавить: new File(*); -> (File file = new File(classloader.getResource("file.csv").getFile()); И даже если так, то всё равно вылетает эта ошибка...

Comment: давайте доведем до конца

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111128/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-arthur).